# Is an int pointer an array of ints?

Tags: c

I have been following some examples that declare an int pointer

```
int *myInt;
```

and then turn that pointer into an array

```
myInt = (int*)malloc(1024);
```

this checks out

```
myInt[0] = 5; 
cout << myInt[0]; // prints 5
myInt[1] = 7;
cout << myInt[1]; // prints 7
```

I thought an int pointer was a pointer to an int and never anything else. I know that pointers to strings just point to the first character of the string but it looks like the same sort of thing is happening here with an array of ints. But then if what we want is an array of ints why not just create an array of ints instead of a pointer to an int?

By the way I am interested in how this works in C not C++. This is in a C++ file but the relevant code is in C.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Comment: And you do not freaking cast `void *` pointers explicitly in C...

Comment: An int pointer is not an array of ints. Pointers point to an address in memory. Addresses are ints. So, if I'm not mistaken, when you malloc the array, you are storing in `*myInt` the address of the array that is being allocated.

Comment: generally you also use `malloc ( n * sizeof(int) )`, because otherwise the number of ints you get might be platform dependent, since you reserve 1024 bytes. Which is usually not what someone wants.

Comment: @jonhopkins - No, addresses aren't `int`s, and the address is being stored in `myInt`, not in `*myInt`.

Comment: To the OP - you might find [The C Book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/) a useful reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alternative syntax for accessing items pointed by a pointer - the square brackets. This syntax lets you access data through pointers as if the pointer were an array (of course, pointers are *not* arrays). An expression `a[i]` is simply an alternative form of writing `*(a+i)`<sup>*</sup> .

When you allocate dynamic storage and assign it to `myInt`, you can use the pointer like a dynamic array that can change size at runtime:

```
myInt = malloc(1024*sizeof(int)); // You do not need a cast in C, only in C++
for (int i = 0 ; i != 1024 ; i++) {
    myInt[i] = i; // Use square bracket syntax
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != 1024 ; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(myInt+i)); // Use the equivalent pointer syntax
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup>  Incidentally, commutativity of `+` lets you write `4[array]` instead of `array[4]`; don't do that!

Comment: @AK4749 To be fair, I never thought about it either, until I started working for a company that explicitly prohibited this sort of expressions in their coding manual (the manual said something to the effect that "if we ever catch you writing `4[array]`, you're fired").

Answer (score 12):

> Is an int pointer an array of ints?

No.

> I thought an int pointer was a pointer to an int and never anything else

That's right. [Pointers are pointers, arrays are arrays.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

What confuses you is that pointers can point to the first element of arrays, and arrays can decay into pointers to their first element. And what's even more confusing: pointers have the **same syntax** for dereferencing and pointer arithmetic that arrays utilize for indexing. Namely,

```
ptr[i]
```

is equivalent with

```
*(ptr + i)
```

if `ptr` is a pointer. Of course, similarly, `arr[i]` is the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the `arr` array too. The similarity arises out of the common nature of pointers and arrays: they are both used to access (potentially blocks of) memory indirectly.

The consequence of this strong relation is that in **some situations** (and with **some constraints**), arrays and pointers can be used **as if** they were interchangeable. This still doesn't mean that they are the same, but they exhibit enough common properties so that their **usage** often appears to be "identical".

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, and technically no.  An int pointer does point to the int.  But an array of ints is contiguous in memory, so the next int can be referenced using `*(myInt+1)`.  The array notation `myInt[1]` is equivalent, in that it uses myInt pointer, adds 1 unit to it (the size of an int), and reference that new address.

So in general, this is true:

```
myInt[i] == *(myint + i)
```

So you can use an int pointer to access the array.  Just be careful to look out for the `'\0'` character and stop.

Comment: is an array end guaranteed to be marked with '\0'? I didn't think so

Comment: Looking for the `'\0'` character in an `int` array wouldn't be that smart. On most 32 bit systems, there are going to be the equivalent of four separate characters in that `int` you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

An int pointer is not an array of ints. But your bigger question seems to be why both arrays and pointers are needed.

An array represents the actual storage in memory of data. Once that storage is allocated, it makes no significant difference whether you refer to the data stored using array notation or pointer notation.

However, this storage can also be allocated without using array notation, meaning that arrays are not necessarily needed. The main benefit of arrays is convenient allocation of small blocks of memory, i.e., `int x[20]` and the slightly more convenient notation `array[i]` rather than `*(array+i)`. Thankfully, this more convenient notation can be used regardless of whether `array` came from an array declaration or is just a pointer. (Essentially, once an array has been allocated, its variable name from that point onwards is no different than a pointer that has been assigned to point to the location in memory of the first value in the array.)

Note that the compiler will complain if you try to directly allocate too big of a block of memory in an array.

**Arrays:**

- represent the actual memory that is allocated
- the variable name of the array is the same as a pointer that references the point in memory where the array begins (and the variable name + 1 is the same as a pointer that references the point in memory where the second element of the array begins (if it exists), etc.)
- values in the array can be accessed using array notation like `array[i]`

**Pointers:**

- are a place to store the location of something in memory
- can refer to the memory that is allocated in an array
- or can refer to memory that has been allocated by functions like `malloc`
- the value stored in the memory pointed to by the pointer can be accessed by dereferencing the pointer, i.e., `*pointer`.
- since the name of the array is also a pointer, the value of the first element in the array can be accessed by `*array`, the second element by *(array+1), etc.
- an integer can be added or subtracted to a pointer to create a new pointer that points to other values within the same block of memory your program has allocated. For example, array+5 points to the place in memory where the value array[5] is stored.
- a pointer can be incremented or decremented to point to other values with the same block of memory.

In many situations one notation will be more convenient than the other, so it is extremely beneficial that both notations are available and so easily interchanged with each other.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. Here is the visible difference.

```
int  array[10];
int  *pointer;

printf ("Size of array = %d\nSize of pointer = %d\n",
    sizeof (array), sizeof (pointer));
```

The result is,

```
Size of array = 40
Size of pointer = 4
```

If You do "array + 1", the resulting address will be address of array[0] + 40. If You do "pointer + 1", resulting address will be address of pointer[0] + 4.

Array declaration results in compile time memory allocation. Pointer declaration does not result in compile time memory allocation and dynamic allocation is needed using calloc() or malloc()

When you do following assignment, it is actually implicit type cast of integer array to integer pointer.

```
pointer = array;
```